# Select day of a string

Tags: python, datetime

My dataframe looks like this, `df.Datetime`:

```
            Datetime
0       Aug. 18, 2020, 12:00 PM
1       Aug. 18, 2020, 12:00 PM
2       Aug. 18, 2020, 12:00 PM
3       Aug. 18, 2020, 12:00 PM
4       Aug. 18, 2020, 01:45 PM
                 ...           
1176    Sep. 14, 2020, 12:52 PM
1177    Sep. 14, 2020, 12:54 PM
1178    Sep. 14, 2020, 12:56 PM
1179    Sep. 14, 2020, 12:56 PM
1180    Sep. 14, 2020, 12:56 PM
Name: Datetime, Length: 1181, dtype: object
```

How can I select the day of each row? I tried `df.Datetime[0].day` but it says that my value is a string... thanks!

Comment: do a `df['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Datetime'])` first, to convert to the appropriate data type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line of code will give you the days from your "Datetime" column as a series.

```
(
pd
.to_datetime(df['Datetime']) # cast your column to date type
.dt # access datetimelike properties
.strftime("%d") # a function that allows you the specify the format you want to extract, for full list of  options https://strftime.org/
)
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow!  Could you give a short explanation of what this code does?  What are the chained function calls, and how do they help in reaching the solution?